# Системный разделитель

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, separator

Проблема с dataGridView, когда по умолчанию в системе стоит разделитель "," матюкается БД что не может привести varchar к numeric меняешь разделитель на "." все становится ок. Мне не нравится вариант что каждому юзеру надо менять разделитель, подскажите что делать, ведь 100% есть готовый вариант и решение.

Вот что я делаю

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_mainWindow.RowCount; i++)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE newRegistr " +
        "SET departedTime = '" + dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["startTime"].Value + "', " +
        "arrivedTime = '" + dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["finishTime"].Value + "', " +
        "pal = '" + dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["pal"].Value + "', " +
        "kg = '" + dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["kg"].Value + "', " +
        "addKm = '" + dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["addKm"].Value + "' " +
        " WHERE shiftCode = '" + GlobalVariable.sh + "' and sort = " + i + " ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

В БД колонка kg и addKm numeric.

Comment: Вы уже http://bobby-tables.com видели?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я бы привел даный код к следующему виду:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_mainWindow.RowCount; i++)
{
    var startTime = dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["startTime"].Value;
    var finishTime = dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["finishTime"].Value;
    var pal = dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["pal"].Value;
    var kg = dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["kg"].Value;
    var addKm = dgv_mainWindow.Rows[i].Cells["addKm"].Value;

    cmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE newRegistr " +
        "SET departedTime = '{startTime} + ', arrivedTime = '{finishTime}', " +
        "pal = '{pal}', kg = '{kg}', addKm = '{addKm}' " +
        " WHERE shiftCode = '{GlobalVariable.sh}' and sort = {i}";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

> Мне не нравится вариант что каждому юзеру надо менять разделитель,
>   подскажите что делать, ведь 100% есть готовый вариант и решение.
>   Предлагаю на вскидку 2 варианта:

1. Изменить настройки системы на другой разделитель (не факт что у тебя в системе стоит адекватный)
2. делаешь .Replace(".", ",") (ну или наоборот) на нужном значении :)
3. изменить .DefaultCellStyle.Format на такой, как тебе нужно. (не забывая протестить на обеих системных разделителях, если твоя апликушка должна пахать на обеих)

А вообще, апдейтить нужно только ту строку, которая проапдейтилась. Потому твой код вообще в корне неверный, ведь, ты апдейтишь ВСЕ строки вообще. Даже, если менялась лишь одна. А если у тебя в таблице будет 100000000 значений? :)

У тебя есть следующие варианты:

- После каждой измененной ячейки сразу апдейдить.
- Или же сохранять в некий буфер измененные Rows которые нужно проапдейтить. а потом уже из этого буфера апдейтить уже написаным циклом.

Comment: Вы предлагаете всерьёз менять системные настройки на компьютере пользователя, чтобы сэкономить указание локали при конвертации?

Comment: @ VladD совершенно не факт, что системные настройки на компьютере у пользователя адекватны предметной области.

Comment: `А вообще, апдейтить нужно только ту строку, которая проапдейтилась` Дайте пример, или расскажите как правильно это сделать? После каждой измененной ячейки сразу апдейдить? Или есть способ скажем повесить метод на кнопку и прочитать только те ячейки в датагриде, которые были изменены?

Comment: именно так --  После каждой измененной ячейки сразу апдейдить. Или же сохранять в некий буфер Rows которые нужно проапдейтить. а потом уже из этого буфера апдейтить даным циклом.